# Gemini returns error: 400 Multiturn chat is not enabled for models/gemini-pro-vision

Tags: python, google-gemini

I am trying to send a request to gemini-pro-vision model and it keeps returning this error

> 400 Multiturn chat is not enabled for models/gemini-pro-vision

My code.

```
# Create a client
client = generativelanguage_v1beta.GenerativeServiceAsyncClient()
content1 = build_content("user", image, text)
contents2 = build_content("model", image, "This is a dog")
contents3 = build_content("user", image, "Are you Sure?")

request = generativelanguage_v1beta.GenerateContentRequest(
    model="models/gemini-pro-vision",
    contents=[content1, contents2, contents3],
    generation_config=generation_config,
    safety_settings=safety_settings
)

# Make the request
response = await client.generate_content(request=request)

# Handle the response
return response.candidates[0].content.parts[0].text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that unlike the gemini-pro model gemini-pro-image has not been optimized for multi-turn conversations. It only supports single requests.

So in my case I had sent it

- What do you see + Image
- It responded with an incorrect answers.
- so i asked it if it was sure.

You cant do this with gemini-pro-vision it doesn't support it.

If you want to do chat you must use Gemini-pro

Please see [model-variations](https://ai.google.dev/models/gemini#model-variations)

[image]

Comment: When I send "image + text" I get error. It works without text. It accepts only image. I got this error: Invalid value at 'contents[0].parts[0]' (oneof), oneof field 'data' is already set. Cannot set 'text'. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: I have an example for that I will post it in the morning

Comment: Please do share @LindaLawton-DaImTo

Answer (score 1):

Because the gemini-pro-vision model has not been optimized for multi-turn conversations, you cannot use it this way.

Source：[Gemini API](https://ai.google.dev/tutorials/web_quickstart?multi-turn-conversations-chat)